# How to search an array with a string to bring up corresponding number

Tags: java, arrays

How do I search an array using a string to bring up the corresponding number? my assignment asked us to let the user type in a name and then have their corresponding pay come up with it, this is the code that I have so far , I am not really sure what to use to do this

```
import java.io.*;

public class Employees {

    public static void main(String agrs[]) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader keyboardInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        double pay;
        String name;
        String answer;

        //Arrays
        double[] employeePay = new double[3];
        String[] employeeName = new String[3];

        pay = employeePay.length;

        //for loops
        for (int x = 0; x <= employeePay.length - 1; x++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the employee name:");
            employeeName[x] = (keyboardInput.readLine());
            System.out.print("Please enter the employe pay :");
            employeePay[x] = Double.parseDouble(keyboardInput.readLine());

        }

        //requesting a name
        System.out.println("Please enter an employee name to search for:");
        answer = (keyboardInput.readLine());

        for (int x = 0; x <= employeePay.length - 1; x++) {
            if (employeeName[x].equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                System.out.print(employeeName + " pay rate is " + pay);

            } else {
                System.out.print(" The employee name hasnt been entered");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using 2 single dimension arrays consider using a HashMap instead

```
int employeeCount = 3;
HashMap<String, Double> employeePayMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
// ... code to capture input
for (int x = 0; x < employeeCount; x++) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the employee name:");
        String name = (keyboardInput.readLine());
        System.out.print("Please enter the employe pay :");
        Double pay = Double.parseDouble(keyboardInput.readLine());
        employeePayMap.put( name, pay );

    }
```

and then retrieve the pay as

```
 Double payFound = employeePayMap.get(answer);
```

Check payFound for null - if its null, the name was not matched.

Comment: do I use an if structure to check if its null ?

Comment: Can you share those errors? The code is supposed to be a guide rather than a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

**What you have done wrong:**

```
if (employeeName[x].equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
    System.out.print(employeeName + " pay rate is " + pay);
}
```

Here you are printing the whole `employeeName`, not the expected index. It should be `employeeName[x]`. Also `pay` is nothing but `employeePay.length`. I don't think you are trying to print the length of employeePay array here. It should be `employeePay[x]`.

```
if (employeeName[x].equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
    System.out.print(employeeName[x] + " pay rate is = " + employeePay[x]);
}
```

**Better approach:**

If you have something those are paired (like *employee name* and *payment* in your example), better use [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of two discrete array. This is better and cleaner way to do this.

You can not only insert data into map easily, but also you can search data from the map without need of iteration that you have done for searching in your code.

Comment: oh okay , ive never used a map before so that's kind of new to me , would it still work if I use the way I am currently doing it? I am only in grade 12 so I am not that advanced yet

Comment: Yes, your current approach may work after some fix. But I''ll put emphasis on going with the better approach here. As it is an assignment, I bet your teacher will appreciate (and may expect too) that you are using map instead of array.

Comment: okay I will try using the hash map instead then , your probably right , it will work out better in the end , thanks